# Render to window framebuffer and FBO to save full scale texture image

Tags: opengl, fbo

I would like to save the output of my image processing OpenGL shader program to an image file and also display the result on the screen. I know how to save the window framebuffer using `glReadPixels()`. However, the resolution of the screen is smaller than the dimensions of the image.

If I render to an FBO, do I need to call `glDrawArrays()` again after saving and unbinding the FBO to see the results on the screen? Or is it possible to tell the window framebuffer to render from the FBO without having to run the shader program a second time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the rendered image in the RBO, you can read the pixels directly by setting which buffer OpenGL will read the pixels from by calling `glReadBuffer`.  In your particular case, setting the read buffer to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT<i>` should do the trick.  See the [glDrawBuffer man page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadBuffer.xml) for details.

In order to display the image in the FBO: yes, you will need to make an additional rendering pass to copy the FBO's image into the default frame buffer.  You an either bind the FBO as a texture, and render geometry, as you suggest, to get the image on the screen, or, you may be able to use `glBlitFramebuffer` to simplify the copying and image filtering.

Comment: I'm assuming your "No" reply is to the second part of my question. Therefore, I do need to call `glDrawArrays()` again after rendering to the texture attached to the FBO in order to display the results on the screen. So, I should render to the FBO, call `glReadBuffer()` with the color attachment that I rendered to, then call `glReadPixels()` to save the results. After that, I will have to call `glDrawArrays()` again (after changing the viewport dimensions) to render the texture to the screen.

Comment: Sorry; edited to address you additional questions.  There are different ways to accomplish what you're asking, but essentially, you're on the right track that you need to (somehow) copy - by either rendering with textures and shaders, or blitting a frame buffer - the bits from the FBO to the default frame buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have implemented it with a second rendering pass and it is working perfectly. I have the saved image in full-scale, and the screen output is scaled to the window dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

> If I render to an FBO, do I need to call glDrawArrays() again after saving and unbinding the FBO to see the results on the screen?

You should use [`glBlitFramebuffer (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glBlitFramebuffer.xml), the purpose of this function is to copy one framebuffer (***read buffer***) to another (***draw buffer***). Provided you are not doing something unusual like drawing into an integer texture attachment then your FBO's draw buffer should be compatible with your default framebuffer (window).

There are some additional caveats related to the filter method and the type of image you are copying (e.g. depth buffers cannot use linearly interpolation), but since you are discussing "full scale" here, I imagine you are interested in `GL_NEAREST` anyway.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of how to perform blitting and possible issues that may arise. Learned something new. Thank you.